# How would a collection of space faring civilizations treat a race that on an individual level could destroy them?

Tags: magic, aliens, politics, futurology, races

To be as brief as possible I have a setting in the far future. This setting has various races, most resembling humanity to the point that with only a cursory glance you couldn't tell one from the other.

There are only 2 races native to the universe with all the others essentially being refugees from other realities.

The question is, the native races are if left unchecked, willing and possesing access to certain skills are capable of destroying entire planetary infratructures within the space of a few hours but only if they obtain access to certain technology.

It's comparable to a nuke. It's difficult to make, easy to track but if someone gets their hands on it and can break the security locks a single person can destroy a civilization with almost no time to react. Other races have their own little WMDs none provide such an easy target.

I should probably touch on what this tech does and that is... create matter and energy and convert them freely from one to the other (liberally applying all the handwavium on that one)

The only real limitations on this tech are

1 - It can only be used by the native races.

2 - It can only affect matter and energy generated by it. So no turning random objects into world ending objects.

3 - Each unit of this tech can not be manufactured without a fragment of a security AI. There aren't that many of these fragments left anymore.

So how would various civilizations react to such a threat from their own citizens. Theocracies, Dictators, Republics, Oligarchies, Technocracies etc. How would various governments react to/control this?

This is my first post so sorry if I don't quite get how the site works yet but thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it possible for native civilizations to "give up" this technology (like a present day country can give up its nukes)? Or any individual of these civilizations has potential means to recreate it?

Comment: Welcome to WB:SE!  I'm a bit confused by your question.  In fact, I keep returning to the "question" paragraph to remember what it is you're asking.  That much distraction suggests you will get better answers if you edit your question to remove irrelevant information and to clarify the question.  Finally, your "question" paragraph doesn't actually have a question (it doesn't even end with a question mark), so that needs the most improvement.  Thanks!

Comment: If this tech requires piece of guardian AI, why is it only natives that can use it?

Comment: Okay I'll try to edit the post. As for why only the natives can use it let's call it magic.

Comment: Alexander. They can "give up" the equipment and with a little jury rigging it can even be used by non natives but to such a limited extent that it's not worth doing.The ability required to make it work is exclusive to the natives.

Comment: What's the difference with nukes? Willing and possessing access to certain skills (and resources), one man (POTUS, for example) can end the civilization of one country.

Comment: Vylix. It's man portable, can cause a a lot more damage, and doesn't need more than one person acting alone to use. Other than that the equipment required doesn't necessarily need to be used to create world ending devices, it can create anything given enough time.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Roberto. Please note that you can use the '@<username>' syntax to notify one user per comment.